# Creating and Opening Database in Android

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite

I created my **Android** database by loading it from an already created **sqlite** database and copied it from the assets manager into the android created database.

This is the code for my database helper class.

```
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    //The Android's default system path of your application database.
    private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/YOUR_PACKAGE/databases/";

    private static String DB_NAME = "myDBName";

    private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase; 

    private final Context myContext;

    public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {

        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
        this.myContext = context;
    }   

    public void createDataBase() throws IOException{

        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

        if(dbExist){
            //do nothing - database already exist
        }else{

            //By calling this method and empty database will be created into the default system path
               //of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that database with our database.
            this.getReadableDatabase();

            try {

                copyDataBase();

            } catch (IOException e) {

                throw new Error("Error copying database");

            }
        }

    }

    /**
     * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each time you open the application.
     * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
     */
    private boolean checkDataBase(){

        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

        try{
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

        }catch(SQLiteException e){

            //database does't exist yet.

        }

        if(checkDB != null){

            checkDB.close();

        }

        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }

    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

        //Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

        // Path to the just created empty db
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

        //Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        //Close the streams
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();

    }

    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{

        //Open the database
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {

            if(myDataBase != null)
                myDataBase.close();

            super.close();

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

}
```

I am now trying to call the `createDatabase()` method in the `onCreate()` method. When i then install and run my application and try to open the database by calling the `openDatabase()`, it logs the message and throws a null pointer exception
to the database instance variable, meaning it was not able to open it. But when i call the `createDatabase()` from the constructor of the database helper class or from another class, it works. Please i don't know why that is.

Comment: Please post the stack trace for the NPE.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the stack trace, hard to say... but a couple of things to check:

1. Ensure the database has an `android_metadata` table with the locale field (and the value.. mine is "en_US" for example).
2. When your app creates the database, `rw-rw` permissions are set automatically for you/your app.  Suggest you check these for the database you're copying into your `/databases` directory.
3. (Most likely problem): Similar to number 2 above, check file/group ownership properties and make sure they are assigned to your app.  If they aren't, you can do this by executing the `chown [your app's UID] : [your app's UID] /[PATH TO YOUR DATABASE FILE]` at run time with the `Runtime.getRuntime().exec`(commandLine) method.